# VBA passing multiple parameters to SQL through functions

Tags: excel, vba

I have been struggling with this code. I can get the desired result if Iam only passing one parameter, however as soon as I try and pass two I get value error.

for example the parameters I need to pass is for period 202110 AccountCode 412 both are type long.

I set my Rs to execute as such:

```
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT SUM(ActualAmountOrgCurrency) AS AmountOrg FROM Vba_ProfitandLoss WHERE FinPeriod =  AND AccountCodeShort = " & Period & Account)
```

This returns a value error in excel but if I choose only one parameter it returns fine.

full code is here;

```
Public Function AmountOrgCurrency(Period As Long, Account As Long)
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConnString As String

    strConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=sql2016ch01;" _
                    & "Initial Catalog=ODS;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open strConnString

    Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT SUM(ActualAmountOrgCurrency) AS AmountOrg FROM Vba_ProfitandLoss WHERE FinPeriod =  AND AccountCodeShort = " & Period & Account)
    
    If Not IsNumeric(rs.Fields("AmountOrg").Value) Then
        AmountOrgCurrency = 0
    Else
        AmountOrgCurrency = rs.Fields("AmountOrg").Value
        rs.Close
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vba
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT SUM(ActualAmountOrgCurrency) AS AmountOrg " & _
                      " FROM Vba_ProfitandLoss WHERE FinPeriod = " & Period & _
                      " AND AccountCodeShort = " &  Account)
```

You need to build a string which is valid SQL - while debugging it's useful to `Debug.Print` the final SQL to check it for correctness.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've spent nearly a day on this.